# MySQL UPDATE two tables result is not as expected (in what order query executes?)

Tags: mysql

First table `18_6_TransactionPartners`

Columns

```
CompanyName | RegistrationNumber | PreviousCompanyName
----------------------------------------------------------
  tests5555 |  x                 |   tests444
```

Second table `2_1_journal`

Column

```
 TransactionPartnerName
 -------------------------
        tests444
```

Trying to update both tables with, for example, variable for `CompanyName` = `tests111` where variable for `RegistrationNumber` is `x`

Query

```
UPDATE

18_6_TransactionPartners , 2_1_journal

SET

18_6_TransactionPartners.PreviousCompanyName=IF(18_6_TransactionPartners.RegistrationNumber = ?, 18_6_TransactionPartners.CompanyName, 18_6_TransactionPartners.PreviousCompanyName),

18_6_TransactionPartners.CompanyName=IF(18_6_TransactionPartners.RegistrationNumber = ?, ?, 18_6_TransactionPartners.CompanyName),

2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName=IF(2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName = 18_6_TransactionPartners.PreviousCompanyName, 18_6_TransactionPartners.CompanyName, 2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName)
```

As result get

First table `18_6_TransactionPartners`

Columns

```
CompanyName | RegistrationNumber | PreviousCompanyName
----------------------------------------------------------
  tests111 |  x                 |   tests5555
```

Table `18_6_TransactionPartners` all is ok (there is no question; table is only to show situation)

But Second table `2_1_journal` get

Column

```
 TransactionPartnerName
 -------------------------
        tests555
```

However expected to get `tests111`

Something wrong with query `2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName=IF(2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName = 18_6_TransactionPartners.PreviousCompanyName, 18_6_TransactionPartners.CompanyName, 2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName)`?

Suppose, the query at first must copy value from `CompanyName` to `PreviousCompanyName`. Then insert new value in `CompanyName`. And then insert in `TransactionPartnerName`.

But no. From my opinion instead of `CompanyName` value, it inserts `PreviousCompanyName` value. Or at first inserts in table `2_1_journal`?

Please, advice what is correct query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. Whenever referencing fields in the update clause, the values of those fields will be the values before update. So in your case, the last update clause

```
2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName=IF(2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName = 18_6_TransactionPartners.PreviousCompanyName, 18_6_TransactionPartners.CompanyName, 2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName)
```

will get the value of 18_6_TransactionPartners.CompanyName as it was before the update, so tests111.

As a quick fix, you would need to pass the new value in the clause to get the result you want:

```
2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName=IF(2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName = 18_6_TransactionPartners.PreviousCompanyName, ?, 2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName)
```

What you would really want is work with [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) (if using InnoDB engine):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT PreviousCompanyName FROM 18_6_TransactionPartners WHERE RegistrationNumber = ? FOR UPDATE; //plug in 'x' and save the value of PreviousCompanyName
UPDATE 18_6_TransactionPartners SET PreviousCompanyName = CompanyName, CompanyName = ? WHERE RegistrationNumber = ?; //plug in 'tests111' and 'x'
UPDATE 2_1_journal SET TransactionPartnerName = ? WHERE TransactionPartnerName = ?; //plug in 'test111' and your saved value of PreviousCompanyName
COMMIT;
```

Or, if you always want to update the value in the 2_1_journal table, you could simply do:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE 18_6_TransactionPartners SET PreviousCompanyName = CompanyName, CompanyName = ? WHERE RegistrationNumber = ?; //plug in 'tests111' and 'x'
UPDATE 2_1_journal SET TransactionPartnerName = (SELECT CompanyName FROM 18_6_TransactionPartners WHERE RegistrationNumber = ?); //plug in 'x'
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Seems in my situation this `UPDATE 2_1_journal SET TransactionPartnerName = (SELECT CompanyName FROM 18_6_TransactionPartners WHERE RegistrationNumber = ?)` is necessary. Will experiment latter. In such case would not need to update and use `PreviousCompanyName` at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do you have to update both tables in one SQL statement.  I didn't know you could even do this - I would separate them out into separate queries - perhaps that is complicating things.

Comment: I would like to update in one query to save resources (suppose will save resources if one query instead two)

Comment: It probably has no tangible benefit to do this in one statement.  If you have one update relying on the contents of the first update then it's just going to cause problems as the data is not committed within a transaction.  I'd split them out into two updates and put a transaction round each one, if you get the results you want and you have a performance issue then you could look at it again.

Comment: Yes, suppose one or two queries no big difference. Seems at the moment I can do it with one query.... I would not, then would use 2 queries

Answer (score 0):

MySQL makes no guarantee on the order in which the changes are applied to the various tables in a multi-table update statement. To accomplish what you want, you should perform this operation as two UPDATE statements within a transaction.

BEGIN

UPDATE 2_1_Journal ...

UPDATE 18_6_TransactionPartners ...

COMMIT